# LAPACK: ZGETRF with INFO greater than zero but ZGETRI does not fail.

Tags: fortran, lapack

I am computing the inverse of a complex matrix. I execute ZGETRF but U(2,2) = 0. When I compute ZGETRI, the inverse is determined. Can I trust this inverse?

Comment: You can make a check.  Is `A * inv(A) = 1`?  If this is not the case (within numerical precision) then your inverse is obviously wrong.

Comment: is U(2,2) exactly 0 or something $\approx u$

Comment: I would like to know for every case, without having to multiply the matrices, but I can do that. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't checked if U(2,2) is actually zero. But, per definition of ZGETRF, when INFO > 0, U(INFO,INFO) = 0...

Comment: if $U(2,2) = 0$ (exactly, as a return value `INFO=2` would indicate), then the original matrix is **singular** so `ZGETRI` _should fail_ (with the same error `INFO=2`). Not directly related to your original question, but may I ask _why_ you want to compute the explicit inverse of your matrix operator?

Comment: ZGETRI does not fail. INFO = 0. GoHokies, I do not understand your question. Which matrix operator are you talking about? I'm not solving an Operator Theory problem. I am solving an eigenvalue problem and one of my matrices need to be inverted, which is not an operator. Please explain better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered a [similar question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/6770/zgetrf-and-zgetrs-from-mkl-zgetrf-fails-and-still-zgetrs-works?rq=1) when a failed `zgetrf` will be followed by a successful `zgetrs`. In this question, the situation is similar.

To call `zgetri`, you have to call `zgetrf` first. Therefore, if `zgetrf` failed (in a sense that $U_{2,2}=0$) in the first place, there is no point in calling `zgetri` and hope for a reliable result.

Why `zgetri` does not result in an explicit error itself is another question, and probably will depend on the particular implementation of LAPACK/BLAS library. But, to sum it up, since you got an error in the first step of your two-step process of obtaining the inverse of the matrix, you certainly cannot trust the obtained inverse.

The strategy how to understand what is actually happening with the matrix is discussed in the [aforementioned question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/6770/zgetrf-and-zgetrs-from-mkl-zgetrf-fails-and-still-zgetrs-works?rq=1) but boils down to the analysis of the spectrum of your matrix, its singular values, and condition numbers, followed by the investigation of the physics where you matrix is coming from originally.

Since you are interested in the inverse of the matrix (as you noted in the comments) and your matrices are "problematic", I would suggest using an SVD-route process to obtain the inverse as opposed to LU-route. It is slower; however, you will be able to see how the singular values behave in the first place and identify problems earlier and see them explicitly.